# Side menu drawer icon disappearance issue - codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I have applied animateLayout in previous screen which is making side menu icon disappear in other screens. If I remove the animate code in splash screen, the problem is not there. If this problem occurred, the side menu opens with the whole mobile device screen.

Have a look at the issue in [youtube here.](https://youtu.be/DVBhGrB2LEA)

Splash screen:

```
private void showSplashForm1() {

    Form splashForm = new Form(new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER));

    Container parentContainer = new Container(BoxLayout.y());
    splashForm.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, parentContainer);

    Label logoLabel = new Label(theme.getImage("logoMain.png").scaledWidth(screenWidth * 3 / 4));
    parentContainer.add(logoLabel);

    Label carLabel = new Label();
    Container carContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    carContainer.add(carLabel);

    Image carImage = (Image) theme.getImage("car_static.gif");
    Timeline tcar = (Timeline) carImage;
    carLabel.setIcon(tcar);

    Label loadingLabel = new Label();
    loadingLabel.getAllStyles().setMarginBottom(250);
    loadingLabel.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(0);
    loadingLabel.getAllStyles().setAlignment(Label.CENTER);

    Image loadingImage = (Image) theme.getImage("dots_min_time.gif");
    Timeline tloading = (Timeline) loadingImage;
    loadingLabel.setIcon(tloading);

    Container animateContainer = BoxLayout.encloseY(carContainer, loadingLabel);
    splashForm.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, animateContainer);

    splashForm.show();
    splashForm.revalidate();

    //car animation starts
    carLabel.setX(-screenWidth);
    carLabel.setVisible(true);

    carContainer.animateLayout(4200);
    //car animation ends

    new UITimer(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            carLabel.setHidden(true);
            new Home(theme).show();

        }
    }).schedule(4000, false, splashForm);
}
```

Home screen:

```
FontImage homeIcon = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_HOME, style, 3);
Command home = new Command("  Home", homeIcon) {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        new Home(res).show();
    }
};
f.addCommand(home);

FontImage bookingIcon = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_FILTER_NONE, style, 3);
Command booking = new Command("  Book", bookingIcon) {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        new Booking(res).show();
    }
};
f.addCommand(booking);
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

Comment: Great looking app, did you submit it to the gallery?

Comment: thankyou... no it is not completed yet. I am working on it & it has few of the issues like this one as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this associated with multiple different edge cases. In one point this happened because a form was styled with transparent background (I have no idea why that triggered this weird behavior though).

This can also happen because the menu icon size is miscalculated so define the theme constants for: `sideMenuSizeTabPortraitInt`, `sideMenuSizePortraitInt`, `sideMenuSizeTabLandscapeInt` & `sideMenuSizeLandscapeInt`.

If you use the new [on-top mode](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/sidemenu-on-top.html) these sort of things shouldn't happen but since it's experimental I'm not sure if it's the right direction.

Comment: The background is not transparent. I've bg image in splash screen and white bg style in home screen. I didnt show it in above code since I thought it was not of any importance. The on top mode side menu is cool. However I'd have preferred it if it covered whole screen. It looks a bit odd now. I hope the on top mode side menu covers whole screen in future.

Comment: If you read the article there is ongoing work on enabling that. Did you try the theme constants I mentioned? Also make sure transparency of the form is 255 if you derived it from any style

Comment: yes I set theme constants all to 4 but it didnot solve the problem.
 f.getToolbar().animateHierarchy(0); If this line is added in every form, then it works but all the components of the form blinks for a second. How can the animateLayout in one form affect the components in other forms? https://youtu.be/__yTafc5kiY

Comment: That sounds like there is something invalid in the forms that was modified there after the form was loaded and might be triggering this. Try removing all calls to animateLaout/repaint/revalidate() and if you add an element make sure it happens before the form is showing. If you change the UI after the form is shown you need to revalidate() for the form to be valid.

Comment: I tried revalidating every form but it doesnt solve the prob. Have a look at splash screen code above, animateLayout is used to move the car and I think it is used before the form name 'home' is called. If I remove animateLayout, then there is no prob but the car doesnt move frm left to right. More importantly, I've to use splashscreen.revalidate() before carContainer.animateLayout(4200) to make the car move which is a bit bizaar.

Comment: If you use revalidate calls incorrectly you might create a situation where the code "thinks" everything is laid out while it isn't and in that case things won't work and you would get weird errors. This is very obvious with EDT violations (which I assume you checked already) but can also happen to perfectly fine code that just lays out too frequently. If you can isolate the issue that will help

Comment: I've used revalidate calls at the end of every form code. I'll make test case for this in a couple of days if I cannot make it right. Thanks.

Comment: Hello sir, I've filed an issue here #2149: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2149

Comment: Looking at the code it looks like you animate the car container for 4200 and set the transition within 4000 MS which means the animation hasn't finished yet. This shouldn't trigger this failure but I'm wondering if this is why this is happening?

Comment: works like a charm. Thankyou shai. I didnt notice it could make a difference.

Comment: It shouldn't. That's the reason for the bug we need to understand how an animation from one form can impact another. They should be isolated